# C# save multiple values

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
class Entity
{
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private static int length;

    Crosswords cr = new Crosswords();

    public Entity(int posX, int posY, int direction)
    {
        length = cr.getSpaceLength(posX, posY, direction);
    }

    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
}
```

And in another class I am creating an array of Entities like this:

```
Entity[] et = new Entity[100];
```

Then I have an algorithm that calculates the length and I want to save the length of each entity, but after that, when I do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(et[i].getLength());
```

I get the same length for all my entities (the length of the last entity), but I set different lengths for them. Why is this happening? What I have to do to save different lengths for each entity?

P.S.

I create the entity like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    et[i] = new Entity(somevalueX, somevalueY, direction);
```

Comment: can you please post how you create the entities...

Comment: Whats in getSpaceLength(...)?

Comment: @BG100 is another method which returns what I need.

Comment: _Why_ did you make `length` static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the static from the length or better do this, calculate the lenght when required.

```
class Entity
{
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private int _posX;
    private int _posY;
    private int _direction;
    Crosswords cr = new Crosswords();

    public Entity(int posX, int posY, int direction)
    {
        _posX = posX;
        _posY = posY;
        _direction = direction;
    }

    public int getLength()
    {
        return cr.getSpaceLength(_posX, _posY, _direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, it's messing my code, and it doesn't do what I want for some reasons.

Comment: So the problem is in another place. Look at the logic, probably is inside Crosswords, you may have an static there too. My change doesn't do anything but delaying the calculation. Check the Crossword class

Comment: I can't figure out what is happening. Yes, I have some static in Crosswords too. But if I remove them I get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That's a different problem then. Open a new question, or improve this one. The code posted here in my answer and the other ones, solve the only 1 value problem.

Comment: I uploaded my question.

Answer (score 2):

The length is static member and one variable for all the objects. It should not be static if you want separate for each object.

*Change*

```
private static int length;
```

*To*

```
private int length;
```

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many
>   instances of the class are created, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Calculating the length for all the objects in advance in given situation does not seem worthy. You can calculate and return the length when it is required. I would prefer to make a property for `length` instead of method.

```
class Entity
{
   private String question;
   private String answer;
   private int posX;
   private int posY;
   private int direction;
   Crosswords cr = new Crosswords();

  *//Make length a public property*
  public int Length 
  { 
      get { return cr.getSpaceLength(posX, posY, direction);} 
      private set;
  } 

  *//Assign the values to private members for later use.*
  public Entity(int posX, int posY, int direction)
  {
      this.posX = posX;
      this.posY = posY;
      this.direction = direction;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good spot. I stared at the code for a while and totally missed the obvious. :)

Comment: @FlorinPop: Well that is the cause of your problem as described. It sounds like you now have a different problem that you need to investigate.

Comment: the problem might be that I create the array of Entities in main?

Comment: Or the problems is that you create all the entities with the same values

Comment: What is not working, are you still get the same length for all objects? Make sure you are calling Entity() method with different argument to get to different length.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I think I was bit lucky to catch that early.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this behavior is that you've declared the length field as static.

> While an instance of a class contains a separate copy of all instance
>   fields of the class, there is only one copy of each static field.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx